# How to subtract a limited number of numbers in a list in python

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I am trying to subtract 1 from the first N numbers in a list that contains 7 numbers. (N being the first number in the list)

```
list = (5, [19, 17, 14, 12, 12, 10, 8])
```

The goal is to subtract 1 from the first 5 numbers so that my output looks like

```
[18, 16, 13, 11, 11, 10, 8]
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to do with the first line of code there...

I believe what you're trying to do is this:

```
example_list = [19, 17, 14, 12, 12, 10, 8]

N = 5

for i in range(0, N):
    example_list[i] = example_list[i] - 1

print(example_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your list in 2 parts. Subtract 1 to the first part and append the second one:

```
t = (5, [19, 17, 14, 12, 12, 10, 8])
N = t[0]  # <- 5
l = t[1]  # <- [19, 17, 14, 12, 12, 10, 8]

>>> [i - 1 for i in l[:N]] + l[N:]
[18, 16, 13, 11, 11, 10, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok try it:

```py
lst = [19, 17, 14, 12, 12, 10, 8] # list

temp = lst[:5] # select from start to 5 - 1 (5 first)

temp = list( # MapObject to list
    map(
        lambda i: i - 1, # 1 -> 1 - 1
        temp
    )
)

lst[:5] = temp
```